# Get date object for the first/last day of the current year

Tags: python, date

I need to get `date` objects for the first and last day in the current year.

Currently I'm using this code which works fine, but I'm curious if there's a nicer way to do it; e.g. without having to specify the month/day manually.

```
from datetime import date
a = date(date.today().year, 1, 1)
b = date(date.today().year, 12, 31)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd really classify your solution as a manual solution; in fact it is a lot clearer, and therefore 'nicer', than the alternatives that all involve date arithmetic.

Comment: I think this is as "nice" as you're going to get. What exactly do you dislike about this code?

Comment: Actually I just wanted to know if there's some function to get e.g. the first/last day of a month I haven't heard about.

Comment: `calendar.monthrange(year,month)` gives the first/last day of the month. However, I don't see how that would help your code.

Comment: it looks like you are loosing the last day actually.

Comment: unless you want to take the local time zone into account that might skip December 31 (there are none that I know of but e.g., there are many where December 30 is missing). January 1 may be missing in some tmezones on some years.

Comment: Well when dealing with `date` objects you don't have timezones anyway ;) But timezones that skip Dec30 or Jan1? How is that even possible? :o

Comment: To skip Jan 1:  Dec 31 23:59:59 is followed by Jan 2 00:00:00 e.g., it happened at the end of 1994 in Pacific/Enderbury timezone (I think it is near the international date line). Unrelated: [I love when the tz database says that the date is ambiguous](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/aedb557c7034c26480d0fc2755871bd6355ba6e2/australasia#L1724-L1743).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The only real improvement that comes to mind is to give your variables more descriptive names than `a` and `b`.

Comment: Those were just an example. I'm using those two date objects in a function call.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Fair enough. I think it would help elicit good answers if you described what it is exactly about your code that you find inelegant.

Comment: Also, no need to call today() twice, store it in a variable.

Answer (score 29):

```
from datetime import datetime

starting_day_of_current_year = datetime.now().date().replace(month=1, day=1)    
ending_day_of_current_year = datetime.now().date().replace(month=12, day=31)
```

Comment: Some context or explanation might help those searching for this solution in future.

Answer (score 11):

You'll have some funky stuff going on if you happen to be running this late on New Year's Eve and the two calls to `today()` cross the year boundary. It's safer to do this:

```
from datetime import date

epoch_year = date.today().year
year_start = date(epoch_year, 1, 1)
year_end = date(epoch_year, 12, 31)
```

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing in the python library but there are external libraries that wrap this functionality up. For example, [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) has a timeseries library, with which you can do:

```
from datetime import date
from pandas.tseries import offsets

a = date.today() - offsets.YearBegin()
b = date.today() + offsets.YearEnd()
```

Whilst [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is overkill if all you want is year begin and year end functionality, it also has support for a lot of other high level concepts such as business days, holiday calendars, month/quarter/year offsets: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

Answer (score 5):

```
import datetime
year = 2016
first_day_of_year = datetime.date.min.replace(year = year)
last_day_of_year = datetime.date.max.replace(year = year)
print(first_day_of_year, last_day_of_year)
```

What if we want to get the exact time the year begins or ends? Same thing. Replace `datetime.date` with `datetime.datetime`, and there you go, you got the first last day of year in [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) format.

To make this even fancier, wrap the whole thing in a function:

```
import datetime

def year_range(year, datetime_o = datetime.date):
    return (
        datetime_o.min.replace(year = year),
        datetime_o.max.replace(year = year)        
    )

print(year_range(2016, datetime.date))
print(year_range(2016, datetime.datetime))
```

Output:

```
(datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), datetime.date(2016, 12, 31))
(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999))
```

Answer (score -1):

one genius way to find out first and last day of year is code below
this code  works well even for leap years

```
    first_day=datetime.date(year=i,month=1, day=1)
    first_day_of_next_year=first_day.replace(year=first_day.year+1,month=1, day=1)
    last_day=first_day_of_next_year-jdatetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

use relative timedelta and substract from date object

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime

date = datetime.date.today()
fistOfYear = date - relativedelta(years=0, month=1, day=1)
```

Comment: The OP wanted to avoid specifying month and day values.